# Is there a way to define font weight as medium [Tkinter]?

Tags: tkinter

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow set the font-weight to medium instead of normal/bold.

For instance;

> `font="Roboto 15 medium"`

Right now I'm only getting errors: `unknown font style "medium"`

Comment: No it's not possible. You could mix bold and italic to achieve something like that.

Comment: How? @BryanOakley

Comment: You can create a font object.

Comment: I would appreciate if you show me a quick example :)

Comment: @BryanOakley yes, one can specify the weight, but aren't there only weights _normal_ and _bold_? and the question seemingly asks about other weights. To me it seems that this can be solved by downloading the font with that weight (for example from https://fonts.google.com/) and using that

Comment: @Matiiss: thank you for the correction! I didn't realize that only `normal` and `bold` are valid for weight. This isn't a feature I use often, and all I did was verify that `weight` was an option.